# Parsing XML with class that are uniquely numbered

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Hey all I have the following code that I am in need of finding the class  in:

```
Dim nodelist As System.Xml.XmlNodeList = Nothing
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

doc.LoadXml(tmpData)
nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//entry/content/sp_0:div/span/sp_0:span")

For Each node As System.Xml.XmlElement In nodelist
   Debug.print(node("OrderID").InnerText)
Next
```

And the XML looks like this:

```
<feed
    xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
    xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"
    xmlns:fh="http://purl.org/syndication/history/1.0"
    xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn"
    xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>2006:feed</id>
    <generator version="5.0.0.0" uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn">IBM Connections - Profiles</generator>
    <title type="text">reporting chain for Bill Gates</title>        
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>8</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <fh:complete></fh:complete>
    <link
        href="http://..."
        rel="self"
        type="application/atom+xml"></link>
    <entry>
        <id>tag:profiles.ibm.com,2006</id>
        <title type="text">Bill Gates</title>
        <updated>2016-05-11T06:39:54.908Z</updated>
        <category term="profile" scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"></category>
        <contributor>
            <name>Bill Gates</name>
            <snx:userid>010101</snx:userid>
            <email>Bill_Gates@microsoft.com</email>
            <snx:userState>active</snx:userState>
            <snx:isExternal>false</snx:isExternal>
        </contributor>
        <link
            href="http://..."
            rel="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/profile-type"
            type="application/profile-type+xml"></link>
        <thr:in-reply-to>
            <app:accept>ref</app:accept>
            <app:accept>tag:profiles.ibm.com,2006</app:accept>
        </thr:in-reply-to>
        <summary type="text">Profile information for Bill Gates</summary>
        <content type="xhtml">
            <sp_0:div
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:sp_0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <sp_0:span class="vcard">
                    <sp_0:div class="x-groupwareMail" style="display:none"></sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="org">
                        <sp_0:span class="organization-unit"></sp_0:span>
                    </sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="role"></sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="title">Applications Developer/Analyst</sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="uid">265418</sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="x-profile-uid">010101</sp_0:div>
                    <sp_0:div class="x-lconn-userid">265418</sp_0:div>
                </sp_0:span>
            </sp_0:div>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        etc....            
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I get an error on **nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("//entry/content/sp_0:div/span/sp_0:span")** saying:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

How can I get the internal text **010101** from that class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using XPath and VB.NET to parse XML containing namespsaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949495/using-xpath-and-vb-net-to-parse-xml-containing-namespsaces)

Comment: @DWRoelands **not** a duplicate due to the said question of different class value names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`XmlNamespaceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to define the namespaces used in your XPath, and pass this to the `SelectNodes` method.  In addition, I couldn't get an empty namespace to work for the default namespace (perhaps a limitation with XPath?), so had to define a prefix for that.

Also, your XPath doesn't seem to match your sample XML.  Lets say you wanted to get the value for the `<sp_0:div class="x-profile-uid">010101</sp_0:div>` element, you would want something like this:

```vb
Dim nodelist As System.Xml.XmlNodeList = Nothing
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

doc.LoadXml(tmpData)

Dim nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
nsmgr.AddNamespace("sp_0", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")

nodelist = doc.SelectNodes(
    "//atom:entry/atom:content/sp_0:div/sp_0:span/sp_0:div[@class='x-profile-uid']",
    nsmgr
)

For Each node As System.Xml.XmlElement In nodelist
   Debug.Print(node.InnerText)
Next
```

Which outputs:

```
010101
```

Hopefully you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: How much of the code would change since **sp_0:div** changed to **sp_0:div**, **sp_1:div**, **sp_2:div**, etc which I will not know how many _xx it will be?

Comment: @StealthRT Are `sp_0`, `sp_1` etc. different namespaces, or just different prefixes for the same namespace?  The XPath doesn't care what prefixes your XML uses, just that the namespaces match up.

Comment: It's within the *SelectNodes* so **//atom:entry/atom:content/sp_0:div/sp_0:span/sp_0:div[@class='x-profile-uid']** would be something like **//atom:entry/atom:content/sp_0:div/sp_0:span/sp_0:div[@class='x-profile-uid']**, **//atom:entry/atom:content/sp_1:div/sp_1:span/sp_1:div[@class='x-profile-uid']**, **//atom:entry/atom:content/sp_2:div/sp_2:span/sp_2:div[@class='x-profile-uid']**, etc..

and also **nsmgr.AddNamespace("sp_0", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")**, **nsmgr.AddNamespace("sp_1", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")**, etc

Comment: @StealthRT It still depends on what namespaces those prefixes refer to.  The prefix/alias used in the XPath does not need to match the XML, so in my answer if could be `nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")` and `//atom:entry/atom:content/x:div/x:span/x:div[@class='x-profile-uid']` and still match the XML given in the question which uses `sp_0` as the prefix for `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, so you only need to define it once in `nsmgr` if they all refer to `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

Comment: You are correct. That did work and gathered all the uid's. Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 0):

You should define the namespace "sp_0", the same way you defined the other namespaces (xmlns:app="...") in the root element.

Look at the last line of the element: this is how to define the namespace for SP_0.

```
    <feed
xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"
xmlns:fh="http://purl.org/syndication/history/1.0"
xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn"
xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
sp_0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```