# Cannot parse XML with xmlns value

Tags: c#, xml

I receive an XML file which has on the root node a xmlns namespace assigned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Message xmlns="http://www.myAddress.com/DataRequest/message/">
  <Date>2017/01/01</Date>
</Message>
```

I do not know how to retrive the Date element using XPath, I tried

```
  var root = xDocument.Root;
  var dateElement = root.XPathSelectElement("/Message/Date");
```

If I remove the namespace from the root xml, then I can retrieve the value using "/Message/Date".

I tried to add xmlns to a XmlNamespaceManager, but I get this error:

> Prefix "xmlns" is reserved for use by XML.

How can I get the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using XPath and VB.NET to parse XML containing namespsaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949495/using-xpath-and-vb-net-to-parse-xml-containing-namespsaces)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use namespace when you specify element's name. Default namespace is easy to get with [`XElement.GetDefaultNamespace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
var ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var dateElement = (DateTime)root.Element(ns + "Date");
```

If you want to use XPath:

```
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
manager.AddNamespace("ns", root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString());
var dateElement = (DateTime)root.XPathSelectElement("/ns:Message/ns:Date", manager);
```

Comment: I doesn't work and I do not understand why it should work. There are no nodes in XML file defined with the namespace prefix I add to XmlNamespaceManager.

Comment: @Angela it works and I don't understand why it shouldn't work. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: I just tried it out in LinqPad and can confirm that both Sergey's suggestions work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using LINQ.

Here is a link to the code example:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693115.aspx

here is the code:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("Message.xml");  
IEnumerable<XElement> dateNode=  
    from el in root.Elements("Date")   
    select el;  
foreach (XElement el in dateNode)  
    Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Comment: You still need to take care of the namespace. So add _var ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();_ and _from el in root.Elements(ns+"Date")_

Comment: this is a duplicate question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857172/using-xelement-to-query-for-a-node-in-namespace. @PalleDue good call